# TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData error with $.post() method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

The console show this error. I can't upload file to the server using modals with php and the method $.post().

The modal is this:

```
<div class="modal fade addModal" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="group">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php include 'new_version.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                        
                <div id="operations">
                    <form class="add-form-modal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <button class="fa fa-edit btn btn-success"> Guardar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="fa fa-ban btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> Ignorar</button>
                    </form>
                </div> 
            </div>                        
            <div id="infoAdd">
            </div>                     
            <div id="errorsAdd">
            </div>                     
        </div>
    </div>               
</div>
```

And the ajax is this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add-form-modal').submit(processFormAdd);
//
            function processFormAdd() {
                //Stop form from submitting normally
                event.preventDefault();

                target_name = $("#newtarget_name").val();
                disabled = $("#newdisabled").val();
                iduser = $("#newiduser").val();
                modificatedate = $("#newmodificatedate").val();

                const inputFile = document.getElementById("data");
                var file = inputFile.files[0];
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('data', file); // En la posición 0; es decir, el primer elemento

                var url = "<?php echo url_for('/views/staff/docum/new_version.php?iddoc='); ?>" + iddoc;
                // hay que mirar la BBDD como se llaman las columnas (o en admin.class.php)
                var options = {'idfile': iddoc, 'target_name': target_name, 'disabled': disabled, 'iduser': iduser, 'modificatedate': modificatedate, 'target_file': formData};


                if (inputFile.files.length > 0) {
                    // Send the data using post
                    var posting = $.post(url, options);
                    // Put the results in a div
                    posting.done(function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                        alert("Ajax success data perform " + data);
                        $('#errorsAdd').html('<div class="alert alert-success"> Información añadida con exito </div>').delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");

                        $('.add-form-modal')[0].reset();
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            location.reload();
                        }, 3000);

                    }).fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#info').html('<div class="alert alert-error"> Error al procesar la información </div>').fadeOut(5000);
                        alert("Ajax show throws: " + errorThrown);
                        if (console && console.log) {
                            console.log("La solicitud a fallado: " + textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // El usuario no ha seleccionado archivos
                    alert("Selecciona un archivo");
                }
            }
        });
```

But show this error and I can't upload. In the others stackoverlfow pages I finded that with **$.ajax()** method need to add **processData: false** but here, with the **$.post()** method, what I need to do? .

Mention that before implementing bootstrap modals the app worked only with php and upladed perfectly the file on the server.

Thanck a lot!

Comment: Can you tell me where did you get this variable `iddoc`

Comment: I pick up good this variable `iddoc = $("#newiddoc").val();` because I see the value